# C++ DrawText And TextOut Displaying Nothing

Tags: c++, winapi

Where do I use TextOut or DrawText?

```
TCHAR text[]= "My First Window";
     RECT rc;
     HDC wdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
     GetClientRect (hWnd, &rc);
     SetTextColor(wdc, 0x00000000);
     SetBkMode(wdc,TRANSPARENT);
     rc.left=40;
     rc.top=10;
     TextOut(hdc,rc.left,rc.top,text,ARRAYSIZE(text));
     EndPath(hdc);
     SelectClipPath(hdc, RGN_AND);
```

I'm placing this in `WM_CREATE:`

The result is a blank window.  I can provide more code if need be, but it's just a standard Win32 blank window.

This is my first real Win32 application and I've googled and searched for an hour without finding the answer to my question.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows doesn't work like that. You can't just paint once and expect what you painted to be displayed forever. Your window probably isn't even visible when `WM_CREATE` is handled.

(as an aside, you are also leaking `wdc` in the above code, and interchanging `wdc` with `hdc`).

You need to handle the `WM_PAINT` message and do your painting in there. Call [`BeginPaint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362.aspx) to get an HDC that you can draw on, and call [`EndPaint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162598.aspx) when finished.

You should get a beginner's book in Win32 programming as handling `WM_PAINT` is pretty basic stuff.  Start with the MSDN documentation:

[Painting and Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162759.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!  I had no idea where to even start.

Comment: Why can I implement buttons or edit boxes to the window but not text?

Comment: @Skathix Because they're windows in their own right, and they handle their own painting.

Comment: If you're trying to add labels, you can use the `STATIC` window class as an alternative to drawing the text yourself.